# When is 'what' used for living beings?

Tags: relative-pronouns, determiners

I have seen phrases like

> 'What judge?'

and

> 'What prisoners?'

But I feel that 'which' is a more appropriate pronoun for living things.Why not 'which' has been used there?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*Which* is ordinarily used when asking for the identity of a specific member or members of a known group:

> A: The government said they would release three prisoners.
>   B: Which prisoners? There are over a hundred of them.

*What* is ordinarily used when asking for the identity of somebody previously unknown.

> A: The government said they would release three of the prisoners.
>   B: What prisoners? There should be no prisoners; they said last fall they had released them all.

Comment: The same principle applies to inanimate/abstract concepts like *What height are you?* - a valid response being whatever height, in whatever units, the respondent feels accurately reflects his height, whereas *Which height are you?* would presuppose a context where a limited number of height *ranges* are contextually known to both parties (valid response being the most appropriate predefined category).

Comment: For completeness, it might be good to also mention "who", which is the standard English interrogative pronoun for people, but cannot act as a [determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner); that is, while you can say "Who?" or "What prisoners?", in normal English you cannot say \*"Who prisoners?", but must instead use "what" in that case.